# use solution from rootsolver in objective function

Tags: r

I'm solving for the roots of an objective function using the rootSolve package. Here is the code, which give me a plot displaying the roots and prints the solutions:

```
library(rootSolve)
P_func <- function (x) (0.11)*(-10^6/(10^4-(x/0.03))+20)*(10^4-(x/0.03)^2/(10^6))
curve(P_func(x), 0, 8000)
abline(h = 0, lty = 3)
All <- uniroot.all(P_func, c(0,8000))
points(All, y = rep(0,length(All)), pch = 16, cex = 2)
All
```

I want to take the roots and plug them into another function:

```
W_func <- function (x) (10^4-x/0.03)
```

Where the value of x is defined by each of the solutions I found for P_func. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Yes. `All` is a vector and your `W_func` accepts a vector as argument. So use `W_func(All)`.

Comment: Thanks @Bhas! I didn't see a way to accept your comment as an answer, but I'd like to give you credit for it.

Comment: I have made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is indeed a simple way.

`All` is a vector and your `W_func` accepts a vector as argument. So just use `W_func(All)`.